# Upload an Image using springboot in linux

Tags: java, linux, spring, spring-boot, multipartform-data

I try to upload an image using `spring-boot`. The app should be capable for Linux and windows. The below codes are working only in windows, not in Linux. I tried in different ways. `getDefaultFolderPath()` is creating folder in both OS if not exists. But `Files.write(path, bytes);` is working only in windows.

```
String imageWindowsPath = "C:\\myapp\\";
String imageLinuxPath = "user.home";    

private String uploadImage(MultipartFile file, HttpServletRequest request) {
    String fileName = "blur.png";

    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        byte[] bytes = file.getBytes(); 
        Path path = Paths.get(getDefaultFolderPath() + fileName);
        Files.write(path, bytes);
    }

    //few other codes
    retrun "";
}

//Creating folder if not exists... This is working for both OS
public String getDefaultFolderPath() {

    String path = "";
    try {
        String os = System.getProperty("os.name");
        if (os.toUpperCase().indexOf("WINDOWS") != -1) {
            File file = new File(imageWindowsPath+"slider");                
            if (!file.exists())
                file.mkdirs();

            path = imageWindowsPath+"/slider/";
        } 
        else if (os.toUpperCase().indexOf("LINUX") != -1) {
            String userHome = System.getProperty(imageLinuxPath);
            String appName = "slider";

            Path linuxpath = Paths.get(userHome, appName);          
                Files.createDirectories(linuxpath); 

            path = imageLinuxPath+"/slider/";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //few codes 

    return path;
}
```

Please suggest me a solution if anyone knows. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The state of the art is to define directories as configuration that's external to the code and that can be easily adapted to the environment you're deploying to. Not to try and detect on which OS you're running.

Comment: @kumesana but this doesn't work even, any idea?

Comment: You seem to return another path than the one you create. If it is necessary to create a path in linux, you probably need to create it all.

Comment: Its creating the path in linux

Comment: You are creating linuxpath and returning imageLinuxPath+"slider/". If they are the same, you should change your code to reflect it.

Comment: I think u didnt check the code, i just return a string. but path is automatically created ` Path linuxpath = Paths.get(userHome, appName);          
                Files.createDirectories(linuxpath); `

Comment: Also the code doesn't compile, for example, `retrun "";`

Comment: There are few codes, for easiness for viewers i  return empty string

Comment: I think you are not reading the code ;-) You are assigning `path = imageLinuxPath+"slider/"` but the content of imageLinuxPath seems to be a property name. So the content of path has nothing to do with the directory you just created.

Comment: @JanLarsen Its woring, its creating a folder inlinux, i worry about how to write(upload the image)

Answer (score 0):

```
String imageLinuxPath = "user.home";    

        String userHome = System.getProperty(imageLinuxPath);
        String appName = "slider";

        Path linuxpath = Paths.get(userHome, appName);          
            Files.createDirectories(linuxpath);
```

creates a directory based on the environment variable "user.home"

```
        path = imageLinuxPath+"slider/";
return path;
```

returns "user.homeslider/"

Since the content of the environment variable user.home is probably not "user.home", the path will not be the directory that was created.
This means that you are trying to write to a directory that does not exist.

I would like to add that the difference between Windows and Linux is entirely your own creation. Java can treat them exactly the same way if you have a Windows property with the home path.

Comment: Im sorry, My mistake, it was a mistake while writing here, i will edit it. but its not working :'(

Comment: You should not post imaginary code and expect help.

Comment: Ims sorry, i didnt check when typing, i I said its creating the folder, so the problem with Files.write()?

Comment: Did you even read my answer? Given the code in the question, I have explained why write() does not work. If the code does not show your problem, how do you expect helpl?